# How to disable the special characters in eclipse java class

Tags: android, eclipse

I don't know how it has been enabled, please help me to disable this special characters in eclipse java class.
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is under Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors. There is a `checkBox` labeled "Show whitespace characters". If you unchecks this the editor switches back to normal.

Comment: welcome. If it worked you can accept my answer too :)

Comment: sure i will mark it as answer, is there any shortcut to enable it on right clicking on the class file because i accidently enable it there but i dono the steps.

Comment: There is no option of it on right click. But you can open preferences on your right click.

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck the highlighted checkbox from preference

[image]